# Postback issues with firefox on an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, firefox, postback, partial

I have a strange problem on an aspx page. In short, I have 3 radio buttons and a table on the page. When the user activates the middle radio button two text boxes and a button is shown to the user. The button serves as a way to post back the page. Anyway, the postback should be only a partial postback. Everything works fine in IE but in Firefox I found out that if I click outside of the two text boxes and then hit the refresh button, the whole page is posted back instead of a partial postback. If I select a date from the two text boxes and don't get the cursor out of one of the text boxes and then hit the button, only a partial post back is performed, which is what I want. The question is, how could I resolve this issue with Firefox ?

The page basically looks like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
<asp:RadioButtonList>

<div>
   ...
   <asp:TextBox />
   ...
   <asp:TextBox />
   ...
   <asp:Button ID="refreshButton" />
</div>
...
<asp:UpdatePanel>
   <ContentTemplate>
      <GridView ... />
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger 
         ControlID="filterRBL" 
         EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger 
         ControlID="numberOfRecordsPerPageDDL" 
         EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger 
         ControlID="refreshButton" 
         EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some of your code/HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put the group of controls into a `<asp:Panel>` tag and/or change the UpdateMode="Conditional" on your UpdatePanel tag

Comment: I tried to insert the tag UpdateMode="Conditional" but it doesn't help, I have the same issues.